# LibreOffice Calc: when copying an empty cell, it turns into a zero?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice, cells

In a LibreOffice spreadsheet, when I want to duplicate a cell's content, I use `=<source coords>`. For example if I want cell A2 to contain a duplicate of whatever is in A1, I fill in `=A1` in A2.

Works fine for numbers, formulas, and text, *except* when a cell is empty. For some reason the duplicate cell then contains a **number zero** instead of empty. Apparently if a cell is empty, it enforces the content to be a number or something.

Example:

[image: example]

The second row are all copies of the first row. See that zero in C2, while C1 is empty?

How do I make an *exact* copy of a cell, regardless its type, so that a copy of an empty cell also remains empty?

Comment: Excel 2013 has the same behavior

Comment: =IF(C1<>"",C1,"")

Comment: or `=IF(ISBLANK(C1), "", C1)`  [Information Functions](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#Syntax_17)